# JavaScript_Rock, paper, scissors game. How to store the playerScore value and add to it each time the playRound function is called?

Tags: javascript

Why is my code adding to the playerScore every time the playRound function is called and never to the computerScore?

My project brief suggests to call the playRound function five times within the game function since I have not yet studied how to “loop” over code to repeat function calls.

My brief : https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/foundations-rock-paper-scissors

I have tried to add 1 to the playerScore or the computerScore (which are declared as global variables with a value of 0) when the playRound function is called.

I have tried using the increment operator ++ and
I have tried using the addition assignment operator += 1

I was expecting the winning players score to increase by 1.

What actually happened:
The playerScore increased by one each time the playRound function was called which does not align with the winner results.

```js
//write a program to play 'rock, paper, scissors' game against the computer

//COMPUTER CHOICE- generate random choice of weapon
let choice = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
//select random array element from weapon array
function getComputerChoice() {
  computerChoice = choice[(Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length))];
  return computerChoice;
}


//USER CHOICE- assign user choice from prompt input
function getPlayerChoice() {
  playerChoice = prompt('Choose your weapon', 'rock, paper or scissors?');
  return playerChoice;
}


//assign values to player variables 
const playerSelection = getPlayerChoice().toLowerCase();
const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();


//message to return to player
let youWin = `You win, ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`;
let youLose = `You lose, ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`;
let youDraw = `It's a draw!`;
//put message options into an array
let message = [youWin, youLose, youDraw];


//make global player score variables
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;


//function to play one round
function playRound() {

  if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
    return youDraw;
  } else if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'paper') {
    computerScore = computerScore++;
    return message[1]; //you lose
  } else if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'scissors') {
    playerScore++;
    return message[0]; //you win
  } else if (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'rock') {
    playerScore++;
    return message[0]; //you win
  } else if (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'scissors') {
    computerScore++;
    return message[1]; //you lose
  } else if (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'rock') {
    computerScore++;
    return message[1]; //you lose
  } else if (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'paper') {
    playerScore++;
    return message[0]; //you win
  } else {
    return ('oops! Type rock, paper or scissors!')
  }
}


//function to play five rounds and report player as winner or loser at the end
function game() {

  //check code: what values are assigned to player selections?
  console.log('player ', playerSelection);
  console.log('computer ', computerSelection);

  playRound();
  playRound();
  playRound();
  playRound();
  playRound();

  return playRound();
}

console.log(game());
console.log(computerScore);
console.log(playerScore);
```

Comment: It seems that getPlayerChoice and getComputerChoice are called only once, so the values will be the same for all rounds ? 
However, this seems to be quite a specific question, and it might not be relevant for other users on this site. It might be better suited for the forum of your learning / tutorials site from where this project stems.

Comment: You prompt for the user choice once, just like you generate a random choice for the computer once. If you run that function 5 times, it will be 5 times the same result. So the score is correct. You just play the same game 5 times.

Comment: Thanks both for your help. I hadn't understood that we should only post general questions. Point taken. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some small changes will resolve your issues. Getting the player choice and computer choice in each round rather than only once is the main change. We'll also generate the youWin, youLose etc. messages at the same time.

```js
//write a program to play 'rock, paper, scissors' game against the computer

//COMPUTER CHOICE- generate random choice of weapon
let choice = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
//select random array element from weapon array
function getComputerChoice() {
  computerChoice = choice[(Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length))];
  return computerChoice;
}

//USER CHOICE- assign user choice from prompt input
function getPlayerChoice() {
  playerChoice = prompt('Choose your weapon', 'rock, paper or scissors?');
  return playerChoice;
}

//make global player score variables
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

//function to play one round
function playRound() {

  //assign values to player variables 
  const playerSelection = getPlayerChoice().toLowerCase();
  const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();

  //check code: what values are assigned to player selections?
  console.log('player:', playerSelection);
  console.log('computer:', computerSelection);
  
  //message to return to player
  let youWin = `You win, ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`;
  let youLose = `You lose, ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`;
  let youDraw = `It's a draw!`;

  if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
return youDraw;
  } else if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'paper') {
computerScore++;
return youLose;
  } else if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'scissors') {
playerScore++;
return youWin;
  } else if (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'rock') {
playerScore++;
return youWin;
  } else if (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'scissors') {
computerScore++;
return youLose;
  } else if (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'rock') {
computerScore++;
return youLose;
  } else if (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'paper') {      playerScore++;
return youWin;
  } else {
return ('oops! Type rock, paper or scissors!')
  }
}

//function to play five rounds and report player as winner or loser at the end

function game() {
  for(let round = 0; round < 5; round++) {
console.log(`Round #${round+1}`)
console.log(playRound())
  }
}

game()
console.log('Computer score:', computerScore);
console.log('Player score:', playerScore);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Computer score is always 0. Drop computerScore = computerScore++ to fix it :)

Comment: Thank you @Wimanicesir, that has helped.

Comment: Thank you @Terry Lennox, I'll look into loops now to better understand the code you have given me.